# What's the best answer that suits the following statement

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

What's the proper answer for "Don't know what I'm doing here"?

> "Nor do I"
>
> "Neither do I"
>
> "Neither am I"
>
> "Nor am I" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Neither do I" is the preferred response, which is a contracted version of

> Neither you nor I knows what he [or she] is doing here.

Comment: Your verb looks like it is in the 3rd person, but your disjunction is of the 2nd and 1st person. That sounds ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @tchrist: I'll take your word for it. In my defense, I'm a rhetorician, not a grammarian. (Not that there's anything wrong with being a grammarian!)